# How to include my own Apache.conf with main configuration file

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have VPS server with cpanel/whm installed. Now cpanel installs its own Apache configuration files and it says that chnages will be lost as cpanels rewrites that.

Now i want to have my own stuff in http.conf file.

Is there any way that i can mention to cpanel to always include my.conf file during apache conf file generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an included directory in the http.conf file that cpanel writes.  You can add your file to that directory.

Search through http.conf for the word "include".  The path following include will tell you what files and directories contain extra instructions.

Once you've added your file, restart apache.